# how to update a single attribute of an item in a table using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to update only one piece of information from a user saved in the database, and cakephp accepts an array of values for each attribute, but I don't have values for other attributes and cakephp will not update the row because it is expecting all the values found in the row.

Comment: show some code and what error messages you are getting

Comment: Thank you for editing my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First Way : Create new a Query object using query():

```
       $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
       $query = $users->query();
       $query->update()
       ->set(['is_active' => true])
       ->where(['id' => $id])
       ->execute();
```

> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

---

> Second Way: Using PatchEntity

---

using the fieldList()  option when creating or merging data into an entity:

this will allow you to only update or insert field u want

```
         $user = $this->Users->get($id);
         if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {

            //assume $this->request->data Contains field as ['name' => 'myname', 'title' => 'Hacked!'];

            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
                  'fieldList' => ['title']]);
             // Only allow title to be changed

            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your user has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your user.'));
        }
```

> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 0):

To update a single attribute in your model use set method and pass an array of only those fields that you update.
For example, you can try something like this.

```
$this->Model->read(null, $id);
$this->Model->set(array(
      'fieldname' => 'value',
));
$this->Model->save();
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```
$this->ModelName->id = $id;
$this->ModelName->saveField('fieldname', 'New Value');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cakephp 2.x so you can use

```
$this->ModelName->id = $id;
$this->ModelName->saveField('fieldName', 'new value');
```

If you are using cakephp 3.x so you have to use

```
$model = $this->ModelName->get($id);
$model = $this->ModelName->patchEntity($model,['fieldName'=>'new value'])
$this->ModelName->save($model);
```

OR

```
$model = $this->ModelName->get($id);
$model->fieldName = 'new value';
$this->ModelName->save($model);
```

For more information see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data

Comment: "$model = $this->ModelName->patchEntity($model,['fieldName'=>'new value'])" worked fine, but you'll have to explicitly assign the new value on the field. This can't access the value from the view. 

"$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
                  'fieldList' => ['title']]);
             // Only allow title to be changed" from @pradeep worked well, and dynamic.